# Why does urlfetch() give me "Service invoked too many times for one day" in this context using GAS to get API data?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, google-apps-script

I've been trying to get all candidates from Catsone into a Google Sheet and although the code is apparently according to their API instruction, I'm getting the above mentioned error and I'm not sure where to look for the issue.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
const API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

function getallcandidates() {
  const url = 'https://api.catsone.com/v3/candidates';
  const params = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token' + API_KEY
    }
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  const data = response.getContentText();
  const json = JSON.parse(data);
  Logger.log('Data: ' + json)
}
```

These are their instructions for authentication: https://docs.catsone.com/api/v3/#authentication

This is what successfully I got whe I tried calling it from Postman:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.catsone.com/v3/candidates", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Sound like you hit a request limit

Comment: Are you using a free API? They often have strict limits to prevent overload.

Comment: @Barmar this is actually in a paid version. I got the api key and all.

Comment: In your situation, how do you run the function `getAllCandidates`?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, right now, I'm calling/testing it directly in the script editor. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that if you run the script as the custom function for the multiple cells, the number of requests will be large. But, from your replying, when the script is run with the script editor as the test, I thought that the number of requests is not large. So about your error message, how many quotas of the API in one day is?

Comment: Quota is 500 requests per hour, @Tanaike!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, if your test is not over the quotas, I'm worried that the script might be run by other methods or it might be a bug. So for example, how about waiting for be reset the quotas and testing it again?

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you, @Tanaike!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided Javascript and `This is what successfully I got whe I tried calling it from Postman:`, I proposed modification points. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your added Javascript and your Google Apps Script, if the value of `const API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";` has no space at the top character, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
'Authorization': 'Token' + API_KEY
```

##### To:

```
'Authorization': 'Token ' + API_KEY
```

- From your additional Javascript, `'Token'` is modified to `'Token '`.